# Updating a shared variable among threads

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a master list where each entry contains a string array. There is also a slave list which is actually a hash set and each entry is a string. I have wrote two threads to search an item from the slave list in the master list.

There is a member class for stat and I initialize it right before issuing the threads (and not the constructor). Each thread increments the stat by 1 when he wants to search a slave item in the master list.

While in the real code, the master list for each thread is unique, the following sample code uses one master list for two threads.

```
class myClass {
  private List<String []> mainList;
  private HashSet<String> slaveList;
  private int nThread;
  private int stat;
  public myClass(int i)
  {
    nThread = i;
    mainList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    slaveList = new HashSet<>();
    String [] str1 = {"a1", "a2", "a3"}; 
    String [] str2 = {"b1", "b2", "b3"};
    mainList.add(str1); mainList.add(str2);
    slaveList.add("b2"); slaveList.add("a3");
  }
  public void doProcess() {
    stat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nThread; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        final List<String []> m = mainList;
        final HashSet<String> s = slaveList;
        new Thread(() -> {
            search(m, s, index);   
            System.out.println("done");
        }).start();
    }
  }
  public void search( List<String []> m, HashSet<String> s, int index )
  {
    Iterator<String> itr;
    for ( int x = 0; x < m.size(); x++ ) {
      itr = s.iterator(); 
      while(itr.hasNext()){
        ++stat;
        System.out.println("index=" + index + " master id=" + x + " slave=" + itr.next() + " stat=" + stat);
      }
    }  
  }
}
public class Threadtest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    myClass mc = new myClass(2);
    mc.doProcess();
  }
}
```

The output however looks odd!!

```
index=0 master id=0 slave=b2 stat=1
index=1 master id=0 slave=b2 stat=1
index=0 master id=0 slave=a3 stat=2
index=1 master id=0 slave=a3 stat=3
index=0 master id=1 slave=b2 stat=4
index=1 master id=1 slave=b2 stat=5
index=0 master id=1 slave=a3 stat=6
index=1 master id=1 slave=a3 stat=7
done
done
```

The second line should print `stat=2`. It seems that there is a concurrency issue here. The second thread reads the old value of `stat` which is 0 but the first thread had to increment it by 1 before the second thread.

The output of another run is

```
index=0 master id=0 slave=b2 stat=2
index=0 master id=0 slave=a3 stat=3
index=0 master id=1 slave=b2 stat=4
index=1 master id=0 slave=b2 stat=2
index=0 master id=1 slave=a3 stat=5
index=1 master id=0 slave=a3 stat=6
done
index=1 master id=1 slave=b2 stat=7
index=1 master id=1 slave=a3 stat=8
done
```

As you can see, the stat is printed as 2 on the first line!!
How that can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is a synchronization problem in your code.

You might want to use `synchronized` block for accessing `stat` variable.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: Why that is happening then? I can not understand such outputs.

Comment: @mahmood: You cannot predict the scheduling of threads. It is non-deterministic. That's why you have to synchronized the shared resources among multiple threads.

Comment: I used `synchronized(this) {++stat;}` but the result is still odd as before.

Comment: @mahmood: What kind of odd result?

Comment: For example, I see the first line prints `stat=2`. You can run that code snippet.

Comment: @mahmood: That's the synchronization issue with your output to console. You need to put your `println` calls also in the `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 1):

You could synchronize the part where you use the shared variable:

```
  while(itr.hasNext()){
    int localStat;
    synchronized(this) {
        localStat = ++stat;
    }
    System.out.println("index=" + index + " master id=" + x + " slave=" + itr.next() + " stat=" + localStat );
  }
```

But the lists are still shared and unprotected.